# Insert Custom Tag Html String into Article or other content

Tags: php, html

Anyone know a way or a extension that can let me insert a tag or php code that contain custom html into my joomla article or module?

Because the way our dev and live site is setup, I need to hardcode the domain names in the urls. I want to able to simply change the content of a single tag, instead of changing all url one at a time.

for example: href="{custom-domain}/contact"
and {custom-domain} = mydomain.com

Comment: why even include the domain? You can just specify `/contact/` and it would go to `example.com/contact/` when on example.com and go to `differentexample.com/contact/` when on that site. When a url/link starts with a slash, it means go to the root of the site and start from there. The root of `example.com/test/foo/bar` is `example.com/`.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that. but I have multiple dev and live site that need to cross link. For example dev1.com need to link to dev2.com, live1.com link to live2.com

Comment: You could search for a module in [this link](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules). Personally I would suggest you to create a [custom module](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_simple_module) and customize it to your needs.